# Where can I find a free text corpus for the Hindi language?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, hindustani

I need a text corpus for my NLP project in Hindi, however all the corpora I found are not free for downloading. Is there any free annotated Hindi text corpus at all? If yes, where can I find it?

Comment: What is your project?  Why not Wikipedia?

Comment: Wikipedia is not annotated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wortschatz corpora at Leipzig University offer some Hindi corpora of different sizes and genres for download, go to this site

http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/

and click on "more" and than on "Hindi" (the page URL stays the same, but some javascript magic selects the Hindi language).

Comment: OMG Just what I needed. Thanks a ton @jknappen :)

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, I could not find any free corpora for the Hindi Language, however for those who are curious to find out the available corpora (irrespective of the price) here are some:

[Hindi WaC Corpus: Sketch Engine](https://www.sketchengine.co.uk/hindiwac-corpus/)

[Hindi TenTen Corpus: Sketch Engine](https://www.sketchengine.co.uk/documentation/tenten-corpora/#toggle-id-2)

[OPUS Parallel Corpora: Sketch Engine](https://www.sketchengine.co.uk/opus-parallel-corpora-2/)

Comment: Sketch Engine offers a free 30 day trial.  Hindi corpus = hiTenTen

Answer (score 1):

[Technological Development for Indian Languages](http://www.tdil-dc.in/index.php?lang=en) has a lot of resources for research in areas of NLP and Computational Linguistics on Indian Languages. It offers both annotated and unannotated corpora if you [search by keywords in their Resources and Tools section.](http://tdil-dc.in/index.php?option=com_download&task=viewtoolsbyParam&categoryid=125&lang=en)